# ERROR InnoDB: InnoDB: Unable to allocate memory of size 18446744073709544120

Tags: mariadb

I have three nodes to setup the mariadb cluster.

When I use `/usr/sbin/mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster --user=root &` to start the cluster in the node1, but get the below error:

```
2017-08-05 17:41:36 140123776886528 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2017-08-05 17:41:36 140123777161408 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.19-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2017-08-05 17:41:41 140123698513664 [ERROR] InnoDB:  InnoDB: Unable to allocate memory of size 18446744073709544120.

2017-08-05 17:41:41 7f7117464700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140123698513664 in file ha_innodb.cc line 22407
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170805 17:41:41 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=0
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=3
max_threads=10002
thread_count=6
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 21969763 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x7f6fe0b7e008
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f7117463cc0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x7f711ca3dcde]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x2d5)[0x7f711c561005]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x7f711bb7b100]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f7119ed65f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f7119ed7ce8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x73880f)[0x7f711c6e480f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x78fbb7)[0x7f711c73bbb7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x78fcfc)[0x7f711c73bcfc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x82da1c)[0x7f711c7d9a1c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x82dc9e)[0x7f711c7d9c9e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x80ab5f)[0x7f711c7b6b5f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x8002cc)[0x7f711c7ac2cc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x7360f2)[0x7f711c6e20f2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler18index_read_idx_mapEPhjPKhm16ha_rkey_function+0x85)[0x7f711c561965]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler21ha_index_read_idx_mapEPhjPKhm16ha_rkey_function+0xa6)[0x7f711c565ca6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x479524)[0x7f711c425524]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4796a0)[0x7f711c4256a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x47edd6)[0x7f711c42add6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN14optimize_innerEv+0x72f)[0x7f711c432c1f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN8optimizeEv+0x2f)[0x7f711c43551f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDPPP4ItemP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListIS1_ES2_jP8st_orderSB_S2_SB_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x8f)[0x7f711c43565f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x245)[0x7f711c4361c5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4291a1)[0x7f711c3d51a1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x5f8f)[0x7f711c3e14cf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x352)[0x7f711c3e4e62]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x439689)[0x7f711c3e5689]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1fb0)[0x7f711c3e7d10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x169)[0x7f711c3e8bb9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x18a)[0x7f711c4af71a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x40)[0x7f711c4af8f0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x96f37d)[0x7f711c91b37d]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x7f711bb73dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f7119f9721d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x7f6fd9420020): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 16
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=off

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

We think the query pointer is invalid, but we will try to print it anyway. 
Query: SELECT agents.id AS agents_id, agents.agent_type AS agents_agent_type, agents.`binary` AS agents_binary, agents.topic AS agents_topic, agents.host AS agents_host, agents.availability_zone AS agents_availability_zone, agents.admin_state_up AS agents_admin_state_up, agents.created_at AS agents_created_at, agents.started_at AS agents_started_at, agents.heartbeat_timestamp AS agents_heartbeat_timestamp, agents.description AS agents_description, agents.configurations AS agents_configurations, agents.resource_versions AS agents_resource_versions, agents.`load` AS agents_load 
FROM agents 
WHERE agents.agent_type = 'Linux bridge agent' AND agents.host = 'ha-node2'
```

Comment: I have a same problem. but in our case I think It's related to Fulltext index

Comment: Sounds like 2^64-1; that is, a BIGINT UNSIGNED minus 1.  File a bug report on the mariadb site.